# Python 3 - requests module not found but I installed it with no errors

Tags: python, request

Here is what my installation of the requests module looked like:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx newslookup]$ python3 -m pipenv install requests
Installing requests…
Adding requests to Pipfile's [packages]…
✔ Installation Succeeded
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (444a6d)…
   ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 5/5 — 00:00:02
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
```

Here is my python file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from lxml import html
import requests
from time import sleep
import json
import argparse
from random import randint
```

Here is what happens when I run it:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx newslookup]$ python3 nasdaq_scrape_sec.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nasdaq_scrape_sec.py", line 5, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Would anyone know why Python is not finding it?

Comment: Well, did you try doing as suggested and using `pipemv run`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using `pipenv` to install and manage your dependencies, you need to use `pipenv` to run your script:

```
pipenv run python nasdaq_scrape_sec.py
```

The reason is:

- `pipenv install` installs your dependencies in a virtual environment. Which is like a completely separate installation of python
- `python` uses the system installation, which doesn't have the dependencies installed.
- `pipenv run` will use the virtualenv to run your code, so the dependencies will be there.

Comment: Thanks rdas.  I get this error though when running that command: -bash: /usr/bin/pipenv: No such file or directory.   Would't python automatically add it to the path?

Comment: Depends on how you installed it. You can try `python3 -m pipenv` or reinstall using `pip3`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using the pipenv package manager.  pipenv is great because it installs packages inside a *virtual environment* instead of the global Python environment.

pipenv will automatically create and manage a virtual environment for your project. 
To run a script in the virtual environment, you can do:

```
pipenv run python nasdaq_scrape_sec.py
```

Alternatively, you can activate the virtual environment with

```
pipenv shell
```

Then run your scripts like normal:

```
$ python nasdaq_scrape_sec.py
```

If you aren't familiar with virtual environments in Python, I highly recommend reading over [one of the many guides online](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/).